# AccountInfo() and SymbolInfo() return 0 on MT4 startup

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

When I attach a custom indicator to a chart, close MT4 and reopen it, the indicator initialises normally but every instance of AccountInfo() or SymbolInfo() in the first run of start() returns 0.0, causing several functions to throw a 'zero divide' error. When I reinitialise the indicator (without closing MT4), AccountInfo() and SymbolInfo() return the values they usually do. 
If I comment out all functions that are dependent on these two, the indicator initialises without throwing errors after restarting MT4.

Has anybody had a similar issue?

To clarify: the problem only arises when I attach the indicator to the chart, close MT4 and reopen it again; when I attach it when MT4 is already open, AccountInfo() and SymbolInfo() return normal values.

Additional information:

- using #property strict
- using start() instead of OnCalculate() (so I can run the main function manually without waiting for a new tick)
- the requested account or symbol property has no influence on the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens quite often that some data is not available in MT4 at some moment of time. The best thing you can do is to check whether the result is accepted (>0 if you call time, quotes, other data that cannot be zero) or to check the last error, then `Sleep(50)` and try again. Most likely 2-5th attempt is successful so you need that in a loop.

It is possible that you need to know at least Account Number that cannot be zero. After you receive succesful result, all other data seems to loaded correctly.

```
int OnInit()
   {
    if(!initializeAccountInfo())
       return(INIT_FAILED);
    // ... other checks that you need
    return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
   }
bool initializeAccountInfo()
   {
    int accountNumber=0, attempt=0, ATTEMPTS=50, SLEEP(50);
    while(attempt<ATTEMPTS)
       {
        accountNumber=AccountInfoInteger(ACCOUNT_LOGIN);
        attempt++;
        if(accountNumber==0)
           Sleep(SLEEP);
        else
           break;
       }
    return accountNumber>0;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick and elaborate answer! As far as I know, `Sleep()` doesn't work for Indicators, but I'll use [this](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/124379) workaround. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Update: The function works as it's supposed to, but it doesn't receive the requested information from the terminal, no matter how long it waits for. I also tried putting the function at the top of start(), but that yields the same result as running it in init(). (It tries ATTEMPTS=50 times, then continues, causing init() to fail).
I solved it by checking whether the account number is 0 when running start(), and if it is, it continues with return(0), terminating the start() function.

Comment: Oh, for indicator, yes it makes sence to simply return.